# How to install Mingw-w64 cross compiler GNU 7.3.0 on linux

Tags: linux, cmake, cross-compiling, gnu, mingw-w64

How to install Mingw-w64 cross compiler GNU 7.3.0 on linux?

I could install it for C Compiler and CXX Compiler the GNU version 4.9.0. But the does not work with this version.

Edit:

if I run CMake (`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/mingw/toolchain.mingw64.cmake ../src-gen`) I get the following output below.

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++: error: unrecognized command line option -std=c++14
```

If I run all this commands on Windows 10 with Mingw 64 GNU 7.3.0 with Msys64 could be generated and the build runs without errors.

I thought, the problem is the version from my compiler in Linux?

Comment: What have you tried and what problem have you faced with which you cannot solve?

Comment: I edited my question on the top. :)